# Import all Products from magento 1.9 to magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, product, product-images

I am using magento 1.9.4 . I want to import all Product data from another magento 1.9 store. i tried via .csv file but it did not worked. How can i transfer product from one store to another with all attributes . Is there any Extension to do that ? Guide

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can use Store Manager For Magento software (there's free trial available), it allows transferring all entities via export/import and is mush easier than admin